# Comparar Atributos de uma Lista com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola, eu tenho um array com li, preciso comparar os valores dos atributos, todos precisam ser iguais.. exemplo..

Tenho 2 li dentro de uma ul

```
<li onclick="controle.selecionarVolta(this)" data-id="3" data-name="Rotina 3" data-criar="0" data-leitura="0" data-alterar="0" data-deletar="0" data-visitante="0" style="background: none;">Rotina 3</li>

<li onclick="controle.selecionarVolta(this)" data-id="3" data-name="Rotina 3" data-criar="0" data-leitura="0" data-alterar="0" data-deletar="0" data-visitante="1" style="background: none;">Rotina 2</li>
```

Preciso verificar se todos valores datas sao iguais das duas...

data-name, data-criar, data-alterar, data-deletar e data-visitante..

Todos devem conter os mesmos valor, caso tenham o mesmo valor me retorna true;

Estou pegando essas li desta forma..

```
var lista = document.querySelector('.rotinas_selecionadas').getElementsByTagName('li')
```

entao preciso percorrer essa lista, e verificar se todos os dataas que disse acima sao iguais...

Agradeço des de ja ;D

Desculpe, coloquei que era um array, na verdade sao objetos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A idéia aqui é:

- Armazenar todos os valores dos lis em um array
- Verificar se o primeiro atributo do primeiro item é igual ao do segundo
- O critério é que os atributos estejam na mesma posição, pois senão a comparação dará errado

```js
var lista = document.querySelectorAll('.rotinas_selecionadas')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
var itens = [], igual = false;

for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
  itens.push(lista[i].getAttribute("data-name"));
  itens.push(lista[i].getAttribute("data-criar"));
  itens.push(lista[i].getAttribute("data-alterar"));
  itens.push(lista[i].getAttribute("data-deletar"));
  itens.push(lista[i].getAttribute("data-visitante"));
}
for (let i = 0; i < itens.length - 5; i++) {
  if (itens[i] == itens[i+5]) igual = true;
  else igual = false;
}
console.log("É igual: " + igual);
```

```html
<ul class="rotinas_selecionadas">
  <li onclick="controle.selecionarVolta(this)" data-id="3" data-name="Rotina 3" data-criar="0" data-leitura="0" data-alterar="0" data-deletar="0" data-visitante="0" style="background: none;">Rotina 3</li>

  <li onclick="controle.selecionarVolta(this)" data-id="3" data-name="Rotina 3" data-criar="0" data-leitura="0" data-alterar="0" data-deletar="0" data-visitante="1" style="background: none;">Rotina 2</li>
</ul>
```